# Android Proguard warning: can't write resource (Duplicate zip entry)

Tags: android, android-proguard

I enabled proguard and got:

```
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-io-2.4.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-io-2.4.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [joda-time-2.7-no-tzdb.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [joda-time-2.7-no-tzdb.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-primitives-1.0.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor] (Duplicate zip entry [icepick-processor-2.3.6.jar:META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor])
Warning:can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/LICENSE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-lang-2.6.jar:META-INF/LICENSE.txt])
Warning:can't write resource [META-INF/NOTICE.txt] (Duplicate zip entry [commons-lang-2.6.jar:META-INF/NOTICE.txt])
```

What does it mean?
Should I exclude something like here?

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
}
```

Answer (score 30):

You are using a library with duplicate files, is a bug in gradle, for solve use this in your project build.gradle

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude '.readme'
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help. Tried packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    } and that didn't help too.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks! I like my clean builds. :)

Comment: Post logcat after add these lines and post your build.gradle

Comment: For some reason, `exclude '.readme'` does not remove the warning.

Comment: packagingOptions applies in the package* tasks, while the warning above is coming from proguard, which runs before packaging in the release build type. See http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicatezipentry

Answer (score 1):

From [Proguard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicatezipentry):

> **Warning: can't write resource ... Duplicate zip entry**
>
> Your input jars contain multiple resource files with the same name.
>   ProGuard continues copying the resource files as usual, skipping any
>   files with previously used names. Once more, the warning may be an
>   indication of some problem though, so it's advisable to remove the
>   duplicates. A convenient way to do so is by specifying filters on the
>   input jars. There is no option to switch off these warnings.
>
> *The standard Android build process automatically specifies the input jars for you. There may not be an easy way to filter them to remove
>   these warnings. You could remove the duplicate resource files manually
>   from the input and the libraries.*

Comment: But I cant remove them manually bc are inside the libs, so looks like theres no way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding option `-ignorewarnings` in the proguard config file worked for me. It still gives warning for 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' but build does not fail. But use this option only if you are sure about what are its effects. Follow http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#ignorewarnings for more info.

Comment: yeah but the idea is to not have the warnings either!